# how to separate a col into mutiple cols without knowing the final col number ahead of time?

Tags: r

If I have a df and I want to separate `player` by `sep="_"`. Is it a smart way that I can do this without manually check how many col I will need? For my example, it is easy to tell I need to separate `player` into 3 new cols. What is I have 100+ rows. Is it a way to tell how many cols I need to separate `player` into? or is it a way to split `player` without knowing this info?

```
df <- data.frame(player=c('John_Wall', 'Dirk_Nowitzki', 'Steve_Nash_try'),
                 points=c(22, 29, 18),
                 assists=c(8, 4, 15))
## current method:
df %>% separate(player, c('v1', 'v2', 'v3'), sep ="_")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `str_count` to find the count of `_`, get the `max` count, convert to `seq`uence, `paste` (`str_c`) with 'v' to create the column names.  Add `remove = FALSE`, if the original column needs to kept

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   separate(player, str_c('v', 
      seq_len(max(str_count(.$player, '_') + 1))), sep = "_", fill = "right")
```

-output

```
     v1       v2   v3 points assists
1  John     Wall <NA>     22       8
2  Dirk Nowitzki <NA>     29       4
3 Steve     Nash  try     18      15
```

---

Or instead of using `separate`, try with `cSplit`, which does automatically detect and create those columns

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 'player', sep = '_')
   points assists player_1 player_2 player_3
    <num>   <num>   <char>   <char>   <char>
1:     22       8     John     Wall     <NA>
2:     29       4     Dirk Nowitzki     <NA>
3:     18      15    Steve     Nash      try
```

---

If we want to use `str_extract_all`, it returns a `list` column, which can be converted to columns with `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(v = str_extract_all(player, "[^_]+")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(v, names_sep = "_")
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  player         points assists v_1   v_2      v_3  
  <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1 John_Wall          22       8 John  Wall     <NA> 
2 Dirk_Nowitzki      29       4 Dirk  Nowitzki <NA> 
3 Steve_Nash_try     18      15 Steve Nash     try
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(df,  read.table(text = df$player, sep = "_", fill = TRUE, 
    header = FALSE, na.strings = ""))
          player points assists    V1       V2   V3
1      John_Wall     22       8  John     Wall <NA>
2  Dirk_Nowitzki     29       4  Dirk Nowitzki <NA>
3 Steve_Nash_try     18      15 Steve     Nash  try
```

Comment: Wow. All roads lead to Rome. One more question, I was thinking using `str_extract_all(player, pattern = "???")'. Is it possible. If I got the answer `c("Steve","Nash", "try")...` , how can I then separate into cols?

Comment: @Stataq thanks, I updated with `str_extract_all`

Comment: Thanks so much. When I use `unnest_wider` to create new variables on another dataset, I got then names like `v_....1, v_...2`. Do you happen to know why I got `...` in the name?

Comment: @Stataq could be related to the `packageVersion('tidyr')`.   I used `1.2.0`

Comment: haha. I am still using 1.0.3

Comment: @Stataq probably the newer version corrected some of those bugs in name creation

Comment: I upgraded `tidyr` and now it works! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243863/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Without packages you could adapt the `` `length<-` `` by maximum `lengths`.

```
strsplit(df$player, '_') |>
  {\(.) t(sapply(., `length<-`, max(lengths(.))))} () |>
  cbind(df[setdiff(names(df), 'player')])
#       1        2    3 points assists
# 1  John     Wall <NA>     22       8
# 2  Dirk Nowitzki <NA>     29       4
# 3 Steve     Nash  try     18      15
```